Would a degenerate coordinate system be acceptable?
Suppose I’ve got some spherically-symmetric metric akin to the Schwarzschild metric and I render it in spherical coordinates,
$$\text{d}s^2=f(r)\text{d}t^2-g(r)\text{d}r^2-r^2\text{d}\Omega^2$$
for the metric on a unit 2-sphere $\mathrm{d}\Omega^2=\text{d}\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)\text{d}\phi^2$. The metric tensor here is
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}f(r)&0&0&0\\0&-g(r)&0&0\\0&0&-r^2&0\\0&0&0&-r^2\sin^2\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
in the $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ coordinate system (3+1 dimensional).
This is all well and good except for the computational pain it causes me to have $\theta$ explicitly in the metric (and behind a sine, no less!). I don’t take issue with it except when I need to do explicit calculation with it.
Earlier I considered the idea that, since this metric has the property of spherical symmetry, the $\theta$ and $\phi$ coordinates are functionally degenerate into a single $\Omega$ coordinate - because of the symmetry I can always find a rotated coordinate system with which I can functionally interchange the vectors $\partial_\theta$ and $\partial_\phi$.
Effectively, what I can do (or at least what I think I can do) is describe a metric on a 2+1-dimensional manifold as being valid for a symmetrical 3+1-dimensional manifold with two degenerate coordinates; I would consider a 2+1D spacetime with metric
$$\text{d}s^2=f(r)\text{d}t^2-g(r)\text{d}r^2-r^2\text{d}\Omega,$$
$\Omega$ being treated as a coordinate 1-form rather than an abbreviation of two (making this a 2+1-dimensional manifold with $(t,r,\Omega)$ coordinates); the metric on this 2+1-manifold is
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}f(r)&0&0\\0&-g(r)&0\\0&0&-r^2\end{pmatrix}$$
which is considerably simpler.
Fundamentally a vector would need to be fully described in the “upper” 3+1D manifold, since the $\theta$ and $\phi$ directions are still different if degenerate, but knowing the magnitude in the $\theta$ and $\phi$ directions of a vector, I can do all the math in the “lower” 2+1D manifold that I can in the upper manifold equally well, due to the property of the upper metric being spherically symmetric (so, again, so long as I preserve the direction of the vector in the spherical coordinates, I can functionally reduce it to a single coordinate; this would be akin to just rotating the coordinate system to make the $\theta$ or $\phi$ components of the vector zero, which doesn’t affect anything really due to the symmetry).
Also note that, if the direction of the vector is specified so that we can do all the math we need to, we can also greatly simplify calculations like the Christoffel symbols (40 independent components to 18; 64 total components to 27) and Riemann tensor (20 independent components to 6; 256 total components to 81) and what have ye, since we just reduced the number of dimensions by 1.
My first thought was that you wouldn’t be able to follow a particle moving around but then I realized that you could: in a 3D orbit around a gravitating body (that isn’t rotating or otherwise exotic), the satellite traces out a curve in a orbital plane, i.e. the worldline is adequately described as one in a 2+1-dimensional manifold that is embedded in regular 3+1D spacetime, and knowing the specifics of that embedding (i.e. the vector normal to the plane) immediately recovers the full 3+1D worldline.
(This makes perfect sense: the orientation of the 2+1-manifold, i.e. the orbital plane, can be described with two angles from a reference direction, and the position and velocity of the satellite can be described as a function of time in two dimensions, hence four further pieces of information to fully describe the satellite’s position: a total of six degrees of freedom, exactly what would be expected if I modelled this in the straight-up 3+1D manifold instead.)
My question is, in the context of doing math like Christoffel symbol/Ricci tensor calculations, is this technique technically valid? If I do all the calculations to solve the EFE in any arbitrary spatial plane (i.e. a 2+1-manifold embedded at a certain orientation in the full 3+1D space), then by spherical symmetry I then also know about all the calculations in any other plane. Have I led myself astray here? Is there anything that wouldn’t come out right if I used this method?

At least in the vacuum case, Birkhoff's theorem saves (or dooms, depends on what you are trying to do) you here, since your metric is the Schwarzschild metric, for which the above procedure is perfectly valid.

Spherically symmetric spacetimes are examples of warped product spacetimes. Rather than trying to invent your own simplification procedures, look at formulae for warped products e.g. in Abreu & Visser (or in one of their references).

@A.V.S. Is that paper basically saying that a spherically symmetric space-time is a fiber bundle over a two-dimensional Lorentzian base with a two-dimensional round sphere as the fiber? I'm asking because the title mentions foliation, not fibration, which I found in this one: Warped Product Space-times by Xinliang An and Willie Wai Yeung Wong.

@JanG Foliation in the title of A&V is about further splitting of the 2D base into $t=\mathrm{const}$ slices. But for OP's task of solving Einstein equation the section 2 of that paper would suffice, which lists basic formulae. Your reference uses mathematician's notation so some people might actually prefer that.

@A.V.S. Thanks for your clarification on this matter. So are the warped product and the fiber bundle the same thing in the context of a spherically symmetric space-time?
